# Recursive MySQL Query with relational innoDB

Tags: mysql, database, recursion, innodb

I've got a table structure like (simplified):

content

```
 - id_content
 - my_string1
 - ...
```

content_has_content

```
  - id_content
  - id_subcontent
```

topic_has_content

```
  - id_topic
  - id_content
```

Any topic can have multiple 'content', any 'content' can have multiple 'subcontent' (instance of content).
With a given id_topic I'd like to recieve a list of all my_string1 from the linked contents, subcontents, subcontents-of-subcontents, and so on.

I understand "WITH" is not working for mysql but cannot find a nice recursive alternative.

Thanks
daniel

Comment: "cannot find a nice recursive alternative" AFAIK MySQL has no recursion built in.

Comment: There is no recursive alternative in MySQL - try looking into Nested Sets instead: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no recursion in MySQL and also the result you would get would be flat (no structure). The best way is still a while loop in PHP, Java or whatever programming language you use.

The query could look like this:

```
SELECT C.*, CHC.ID_SUBCONTENT
FROM CONTENT C
LEFT OUTER JOIN CONTENT_HAS_CONTENT CHC ON CHC.ID_CONTENT = C.ID_CONTENT
WHERE C.ID = ?
... // you get the idea
```

and in PHP you could repeat the query with the next sub_content_id, until `ID_SUBCONTENT is null`

Comment: So I'll probably stick to a certain amount of joins inside the query, and limit nesting to this level. I don't want to start so many new queries from php, which would most probably be a lot slower.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

**PosgreSQL, Oracle, MS-SQL, ...** have `WITH RECURSIVE` to handle such data structures. It internally uses a while loop to get all the `parent ids` for the current row (we need the child's here instead)

This can achieved in `MySQL` too, you can create a `stored procedure` and reproduce the same behavior

**Assumed/DDL used**

`content_has_content` has entries as

```
content_1
  content_2
    content_3
      content_4
```

I pass the `id_content` as 2 and get the output as

```
  content_2
    content_3
      content_4
```

All of the above are descendants of `content_2`

Fire `call content_details(2);` to get all the child rows for the passed `id_content`

**SQL**

```
###### Stored Routine
DELIMITER //  
drop procedure IF EXISTS `content_details`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `content_details`(`_idcontent` INT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
DECLARE  temp_content_ids varchar(200);
DECLARE idcontent, idcontent2 integer;

SET temp_content_ids= _idcontent;
SET idcontent       = _idcontent;
SET idcontent2      = _idcontent;

WHILE idcontent2 IS NOT NULL DO 
    SET idcontent = NULL;
    SELECT id_subcontent, CONCAT(id_subcontent,',',temp_content_ids) INTO idcontent, temp_content_ids FROM content_has_content WHERE id_content = idcontent2;
    SET idcontent2 = idcontent;
END WHILE;  

SELECT my_string1 FROM content WHERE FIND_IN_SET( id, temp_content_ids );
END//
```

What I basically do is run a `while loop` until I have the last `child_id`, store these `ids` in a `comma separated string format` and then fire a query to get all the rows which have a `id` present in the `var` I just created

**Note:** There are chances you could be having invalid values within your tables, such as row having a `id_subcontent`, which points to its own `id_content`, which could cause a never ending `loop` within the procedure, to avoid such situations, you can use a counter and limit the nesting to say around 50 (or any value as per your requirement) and `raise a exception` if that limit is surpassed

***Some data to play with..***

```
###### DLL Statements
CREATE TABLE content
( id_content int,
my_string1 varchar(200));

CREATE TABLE content_has_content
( id_content int,
  id_subcontent  int);

CREATE TABLE  topic_has_content
( id_topic int,
 id_content int);


INSERT INTO content VALUES (1, 'content_1'), (2, 'content_2'), (3, 'content_3'), (4, 'content_4');
INSERT INTO content_has_content VALUES (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4);
INSERT INTO topic_has_content VALUES (1, 1);
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Actually not only Postgres has recursive common table expresions (`with recursive...`) - all major DBMS except MySQL have it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I guessed Oracle too had it, but was not sure of others, thanks for letting me know this...