# How can I create a query that shows children of an item recursively

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion

I have a MySQL table which has the following format:

```sql
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Company` (
  `CompanyId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Address` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `ParentCompanyId` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CompanyId`) ,
  INDEX `fk_Company_Company_idx` (`ParentCompanyId` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Company_Company`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ParentCompanyId` )
    REFERENCES `Company` (`CompanyId` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

So to clarify, I have companies which can have a parent company. This could result in the following example table contents:

```
CompanyId    Name    Address        ParentCompanyId
1            Foo     Somestreet 3   NULL
2            Bar     Somelane 4     1
3            McD     Someway 1337   1
4            KFC     Somewhere 12   2
5            Pub     Someplace 2    4
```

Now comes my question.
I want to retrieve all children of CompanyId 2 recursive. So the following result set should appear:

```
CompanyId    Name    Address        ParentCompanyId
4            KFC     Somewhere 12   2
5            Pub     Someplace 2    4
```

I thought of using the `With ... AS ...` statement, but it is not supported by MySQL. Another solution I thought of was using a procedure or function which returns a result set and union it with the recursive call of that function. But MySQL does only support column types as return values.

The last possible solution I thought about was to create a table with two fields: CompanyId and HasChildId. I could then write a procedure that loops recursively through the companies and fills the table with all recursive children by a companyid. In this case I could write a query which joins this table:

```sql
SELECT CompanyId, Name, Address
FROM   Company C -- The child
INNER JOIN CompanyChildMappingTable M
        ON M.CompanyId = C.HasChildId
INNER JOIN Company P -- The parent
        ON P.CompanyId = M.CompanyId
WHERE P.CompanyId = 2;
```

This option should be a fast one if i'd call the procedure every 24 hours and fill the table on the fly when new records are inserted into `Company`. But this could be very tricky and I should do this by writing triggers on the Company table.

I would like to hear your advice.

**Solution**: I've built the following procedure to fill my table (now it just returns the SELECT result).

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CompanyFillWithSubCompaniesByCompanyId$$

CREATE PROCEDURE CompanyFillWithSubCompaniesByCompanyId(IN V_CompanyId BIGINT UNSIGNED, IN V_TableName VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN

    DECLARE V_CONCAT_IDS VARCHAR(9999) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE V_CURRENT_CONCAT VARCHAR(9999) DEFAULT '';

    SET V_CONCAT_IDS = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CompanyId) FROM Company WHERE V_CompanyId IS NULL OR ParentCompanyId = V_CompanyId);
    SET V_CURRENT_CONCAT = V_CONCAT_IDS;

    IF V_CompanyId IS NOT NULL THEN

        companyLoop: LOOP

            IF V_CURRENT_CONCAT IS NULL THEN
                LEAVE companyLoop;
            END IF;

            SET V_CURRENT_CONCAT = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CompanyId) FROM Company WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ParentCompanyId, V_CURRENT_CONCAT));
            SET V_CONCAT_IDS = CONCAT_WS(',', V_CONCAT_IDS, V_CURRENT_CONCAT);

        END LOOP;

    END IF;

    SELECT * FROM Company WHERE FIND_IN_SET(CompanyId, V_CONCAT_IDS);

END$$
```

Comment: You _could_ do it with _N_ self joins for _N_ number of hierarchy levels but that's going to be _hardcoded_ and too cumbersome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer:

**[Recursive MySQL Query with relational innoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019105/recursive-mysql-query-with-relational-innodb/16023509#16023509)**

AND

**[How to find all child rows in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042897/how-to-find-all-child-rows-in-mysql/16042957#16042957)**

It shall give a idea of how such a data structure, can be dealt in `MYSQL`

Comment: I have chosen to create a temp table with engine MEMORY and fill it by a stored procedure after creation. This fits most by my current application architecture. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I have added the stored procedure above.

Answer (score 0):

One quickest way to search is, use company id values in power of 2. companyId = parentId * 2 then query database like, select * from company where ((CompanyId % $parentId) == 0 ) 
I tried this code, it's quick but problem is it creates child's id as parentId * 2 and if depth of child goes deep, int, float may go out of range. So, I re-created my whole program.